# C# Compare Exceptions

Tags: c#

I have a piece of code that sometimes throws an exception and sometimes doesn't. Depending on IO and network, different kinds of exception might be thrown. I have a wrapper for that code that shall retry the failing statement, say 10 times until it succeeds. If the exception does not go away after the 10th time, I rethrow it. Until now, I know what to do. Currently, I have something like this:

```
private void ExecuteStatement(Action statementToExecute)
{
    while (true)
    {
        int exceptionCount = 0;
        try
        {
            statementToExecute.Invoke();
            // statement finished successfully
            break;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (!IsFrameworkException(e))
                throw; // rethrow as it isn't a framework exception

            // we know now that it's a framework exception
            exceptionCount++;
            if (exceptionCount >= MaxRetriesOnFrameworkException)
                throw;
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is the following: I want to reset the counter in case the exception changes (i. e. different type, different stacktrace, different message). I know how to compare them individually, but I want to know if there's a standard C# way of accomplishing this.

**Edit:** Here's the code of `IsFrameworkException`:

```
private bool IsFrameworkException(Exception e)
{
    Exception rootCause = e.GetBaseException();
    return rootCause.GetType() == typeof(WebException);
}
```

Comment: You can use miltiple catch for diffrent exception types

Comment: Can you share the code of `IsFrameworkException` method?

Comment: I'd just do `string message = string.Empty; .... exceptionCount++; if (exceptionMessage == ex.Message) { ... }`

Comment: I can't use multiple catch clauses as the exceptions thrown are mostly of type `System.Exception` with a different inner exception. `IsFrameworkException` only does some simple checks on the exception type and message to see if they match the pattern of  a framework exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not specifically related to exception handling, but a simple way to keep counters by a specific key is to use a `Tuple` as the key (it implements equality by value out of the box).

Note that this doesn't *reset* the counter on key change, it justs keeps separate counters for each key:

```
readonly Dictionary<Tuple<Type, string, string>, int> _counters = 
     new Dictionary<Tuple<Type, string, string>, int>();

bool IsCountExceeded(Exception ex)
{
    // create your key with whatever properties you consider to 
    // be "unique"
    var key = Tuple.Create(ex.GetType(), ex.StackTrace, ex.Message);

    // increase counter 
    int counter;
    if (!_counters.TryGetValue(key, out counter))
    {
        counter = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        counter++;
    }
    _counters[key] = counter;

    return counter > Max;
}
```

You can of course always make it more readable by creating your own class, which will implement `Equals`/`GetHashCode` properly.

I am also not sure that the stack trace can be considered as a unique property, and of course, catching and ignoring exceptions is usually a bad idea.

Comment: I don't ignore them, I just left the logging code out as it's not that interesting. The scenario I face are UI tests that are flaky due to the UITest-framework doing weird stuff. That results in tests failing because of the framework. To avoid that, I want to catch the exception and retry.

Answer (score 3):

You should specify the exception type you want to catch. Place the catch blocks in order of most specific type to most generic type.

It is not clear if the exceptions all derive from `FrameworkException` or if you want to use `Exception`, the following assumes the former.

```
int exceptionCount = 0;
Type lastCaughtException = null;
while(true) {
  try
  {
    statementToExecute.Invoke();
    // statement finished successfully
    break;
  }
  catch (WebException ex)
  {
    if(lastCaughtException == null || lastCaughtException != ex.GetType())
        exceptionCount = 0;
    else
        exceptionCount++;

    lastCaughtException = ex.GetType();
    if (exceptionCount >= MaxRetriesOnFrameworkException)
        throw;
  }
  catch (Exception) // if you do not want to log this you can completely omit this catch
  {
    throw; // rethrow as it isn't a framework exception
  }
}
```

See also [try-catch (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch)

Comment: While a good suggestion, it doesn't solve the problem of resetting the count if the exception changes

Comment: Just wondering, [what the h.. is a FrameworkException](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=frameworkexception)?

Comment: Thanks, but again, I can't specify the specific exception type as those framework exceptions disguise themselves as `System.Exception` with a more explanative message or inner exception. That's why I need to compare it in the catch block and cannot use multiple catch clauses

Comment: @vatbub - Based on your code for IsFrameworkException all you have to do is catch `WebException`. Exception catching works based on inheritance, if that is the root type you are interested in then catch on that.

Comment: @vatbub - honestly though you should write handlers for what you know  the code should recover from, everything else should be either not caught or (logged and re-thrown). If you are trying to ignore your own custom exceptions then it is best to document what can be thrown by what it is you are calling and filter on those exceptions so they are rethrown and have everything else be handeled by the base exception type System.Exception.

Comment: @Igor The exceptions come from Xamarin.UITest (not my own Exceptions). While I generally agree with you, those exceptions appear at random. There's nothing to recover from because most of the time, nothing happened. It was just Xamarin having weird problems. And I don't want my tests to fail due to problems that are not in my code.

Comment: Also, sometimes, the exception doesn't even have an inner exception, just something like this: `System.Exception : Query failed with outcome: ERROR`